# Splitting 3d array in numpy to make smaller equal 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array shape =(64, 64,64)
I want to divide it in 8 blocks like the image, each array shape would be then (32,32,32).
How do I achieve this?

[octant box splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOtLL.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You might [*reshape*](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) your array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(64, 64, 64)
b = a.reshape((-1, 32, 32, 32))
```

You'll then see `b.shape` being equal to `(8, 32, 32, 32)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out numpy´s slicing:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(64,64,64)

x_block_1 = x[32:64,32:64,32:64]
x_block_2 = x[0:32,32:64,32:64]
...
x_block_2 = x[32:64,0:32,0:32]
```

This is according to your definition.